# Redirecting standard error to file and leaving standard output to screen when launching makefile

Tags: linux, makefile, io-redirection, tcsh

I am aware that for redirecting standard error and output to file I have to do:

```
make > & ! output.txt
```

Note I use `!` to overwrite the file. But How can I redirect standard error to file and leave standard output to screen? Or even better having both error and output on file but also output on screen, so I can see how my compiling is progressing?
I tried:

```
make 2>! output.txt
```

but it gives me an error.

Comment: what error does it give you?

Comment: make: *** No rule to make target `2'.  Stop.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `>` it enough to overwrite the file. You can use the `tail -f` command to see the output on screen if it is redirected to a file:

```
$(make 1>output.txt 2>error.txt &) && tail -f output.txt error.txt
```

Comment: Thanks
But It says Ambiguous output redirect.

Comment: Note that if I do: make > output.txt
it says:output.txt: File exists. So it is not enough to overwrite the file I guess.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the errors. (Are you using bash?) However, I found a better solution. Try it.

Comment: I am using Putty and it is tcsh. Now it says illegal variable name

Comment: can you use bash? (usually by typing `bash`).. I have no experience with `tcsh`, sorry

Comment: ?? Putty is just a remote access program.  It's not a shell.  When Putty logs you into the remote system the remote system decides which shell you use.  You should absolutely NOT use csh or tcsh.  Those shells have been (rightly) relegated to the dustbin of history, and good riddance.  If you can't get whomever manages the remote account to switch your shell to bash or ksh, then as hek2mgl suggests you can just type `bash` or `ksh` at the prompt to start using those shells.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this simply with pipe into tee command.  The following will put both stdout and stderr into a file and also to the terminal:

```
make |& tee output.txt
```

---

**Edit**

Explanation from GNU Bash manual, section [3.2.2 Pipelines](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html):

> If ‘|&’ is used, command1’s standard error, in addition to its
>   standard output, is connected to command2’s standard input through the
>   pipe; it is shorthand for 2>&1 |. This implicit redirection of the
>   standard error to the standard output is performed after any
>   redirections specified by the command.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading bash/sh documentation and using tcsh. tcsh doesn't have any way to redirect just stderr. You might want to switch to one of the non-csh shells.

Comment: And redirecting both but still having the output on screen?